# provision profiles disappeared

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, profile

I have an XCode project what is already in App Store, now I'm trying to make update but I can't see any provision profiles in this XCode projects. They disappeared. I have 7 project and they recognize profiles correctly, whats wrong with this particular project?

Comment: Where you are looking for the provisioning profile? In Organizer?

Comment: check if profile exists in organiser, if it exist then check your bundle identifier of your application

Answer (score 0):

Check Bundle Identifier in your project's Xcode settings. Does it matching with the provisioning profile identifiers.

Comment: Thank all of You. Problem was resolved by reloading my Macbook))

Answer (score 0):

Check if profile exists in organiser
If it exist then check your bundle identifier of your application.
If it does not exist your profile must have expired, create new one..

Hope this helps you...